# Remote access to dockerized Shiny Server on Synology NAS

Tags: docker, shiny-server, synology

I host a Shiny Server on my Synology NAS. I set up the rocker/shinyverse version of Shiny Server on my NAS via Docker (now "Container Manager") and enabled Webstation to access the apps via my own domain. After initial configuration, all works well and I can also stop and restart the docker container without any errors.

However, **when I restart my NAS, Webstation cannot find the container** and I cannot access the container remotely anymore. Before updating DSM (and Docker to Container Manager), all worked well.

Is there a specific environmental variable I have to provide when setting up the docker container?